# bug in boost::geometry's area_huiller algorithm?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I was looking at the implementation of the huiller algorithm in boost, and it seems to be partially incorrect.

See boost/geometry/strategies/spherical/area_huiller.hpp

In the apply() function, we have

```
if (lon2 < lon1)
{   
    E = -E; 
}
```

which I believe should instead be

```
calculation_type lon; 

if( lon2 < lon1 ) 
    lon = lon1 - lon2; 
else 
    lon = lon1 - lon2 + two_pi; 

if( 2 * half_pi < lon ) 
    E = -E;
```

according to Graphics Gems 5, pg 45 - 46. The comments at the top of the C++ file state that the code was derived from code in Graphics Gems 4, though the code was later corrected in Graphics Gems 5.

I noticed this when trying to calculate areas of polygons on a sphere, where one of the points was (0, 0). In that case, it would always return a negative area, even though the polygon was defined counter-clockwise. Using a point other than (0,0) seemed to alleviate the problem, which got me wondering what was going on.

Can anybody else confirm that this is an issue? Any suggestions for cleanly overriding boost's implementation until this is fixed?

Comment: Isn't it more logical to post this on Boost developers mailing list? And possibly even with a patch?